# Javascript callback firing early?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a call back that logs data and once it has been completed, it then does a redirect.

```
 logAction('Searching Location', 'Search Type: Location - Location: ' + Slocation,  function() {

window.location = "search.php?r=location&tag=" + Slocation;

});
```

My function that I am sending it to looks like so:

```
function logAction(action, details, callback) {

$.ajax({
    url: "../db_api.php",
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'xml',
    cache: false,
    data: {
        sp: spPrefix + "LogAdd",
        type: "xml",
        params: {

            action: action,
            details: details,
            ntid: agentNTID

        }
    },
    error: function(err) {
        alert(err.statusText);
    },
    success: function(data) {

        console.log(action + ' ' + details)
        callback();  

    }

});

}
```

What seems to be happening is the window.location is firing before the ajax call in the function has completed so it never happens.

Is there a way to do what I am trying or another recommended way?

Comment: comment out window.location for testing, the code seems to be doing what its supposed to

Comment: Your code looks fine. Are you sure this code is the culprit? Uncomment the `window.location` line and replace it with a `console.log` statement.

Comment: Should I probably be a POST request IMO